# Pi Zero W not working with RNDIS now

Tags: usb, pi-zero-w

I ordered a Raspberry Pi Zero W and set it up using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xj3MPmJhAPU). For a while it worked and after I shutdown my Raspberry Pi Zero W and used it a few hours later, I couldn't connect to it using raspberrypi.local. It just kept timing out. I didn't change anything on the Raspberry Pi Zero W or my PC since then, what can I do to fix this?

Additional info:

- Host PC = Windows 10 w/ Bonjour
- Raspberry Pi Zero W not connected to WiFi yet (why didn't I do that? I'm dumb)

Answer (score 1):

Everything in that tutorial is perfect. But you need to check your driver (RNDIS) for Pi Zero W. Go to device manager and verify your Pi Zero is detected as RNDIS Device. Please visit this blog for complete guide & installation - [Raspberry Pi Zero W Headless setup – Windows 10 RNDIS Driver issue resolved](https://www.factoryforward.com/pi-zero-w-headless-setup-windows10-rndis-driver-issue-resolved/)

**Possible errors & Troubleshoots:**

- Use proper double quotes(""). It will be different for some fonts.
  Better to erase and type again in notepad instead of copy paste.
- Make sure the SSH file is available. It will disappear after an
  unsuccessful connection.
- Check the proper driver is installed or not. Visit the link for the manual installation guide.
- Verify your pi is connected to Wi-Fi network using [Advanced IP
  Scanner](https://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/). You can check how to use it [here](https://www.factoryforward.com/raspberry-pi-headless-wifi-setup/).